# Calculate changeSet for object that have proxy entity in property for logging purpose - Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity

I have problem with calculating values for change set. I need old and new value for reference entities inside current one. Thing is that those entites are populated with proxy object to avoid loading it from db. Because I already know old value and new value for ID. So code is looking like this :

```
// in code
$entity->setEntity1($em->getReference(Entity1::class, $id));
```

...

```
// event callback for getting diff
protected function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $em            = $args->getEntityManager();
    $uow           = $em->getUnitOfWork();
    $entity        = $args->getEntity();
    $classMetadata = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));

    $uow->computeChangeSet($classMetadata, $entity);
    $changeSet = $uow->getEntityChangeSet($entity);
    echo json_encode($changeSet);
}
```

and **result is** :

```
{
    "entity1": [
        {
            "__initializer__": {},
            "__cloner__": {},
            "__isInitialized__": false
        },
        {
            "__initializer__": {},
            "__cloner__": {},
            "__isInitialized__": false
        }
    ]
}
```

and **desired output** would be :

```
{
    "entity1": [ 101, 105]
}
```

So proxy entity is translated to its property. **How can I avoid doing that and have only IDs instead?**

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is really simple one. I was fooled by printed output of json. Object inside that key of changeSet is not simple one. It's whole proxy object so solution is just to call getId of that proxy and replace value inside change set array.

```
// event callback for getting diff
protected function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
{
    $em            = $args->getEntityManager();
    $uow           = $em->getUnitOfWork();
    $entity        = $args->getEntity();
    $classMetadata = $em->getClassMetadata(get_class($entity));

    $uow->computeChangeSet($classMetadata, $entity);
    $changeSet = $uow->getEntityChangeSet($entity);

    if (array_key_exists('entity1', $changeSet) {
        if ($changeSet['entity1'][0] != null) {
            $changeSet['entity1'][0] = $changeSet['entity1'][0]->getId();
        }

        if ($changeSet['entity1'][1] != null) {
           $changeSet['entity1'][1] = $changeSet['entity1'][1]->getId();
        }
    }
    // do something with it
}
```

I am hoping that this will help others and waste time as I am.